# Make menu dissappear on click anywhere screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

Hi i have this code which works perfect other than once i click anywhere on my screen to make the dropdown menu content disappear i can't reopen the menu. heres the code i'm using along with a jsfiddle demo below.

```js
$(document).click(function (e)
{

  var container = $(".dropdown_content");

   if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
  {
 container.fadeOut('slow');

   }

});
```

```css
.dropdown {
    display: block;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 3px;
    position: relative;
}

/* ===[ For demonstration ]=== */

.dropdown { margin-top: 50px }

/* ===[ End demonstration ]=== */

.dropdown .dropdown_button {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

.dropdown input[type="checkbox"]:checked +  .dropdown_button {
    color: #000;
    padding: 4px 5px;
}

.dropdown input[type="checkbox"] + .dropdown_button .arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 5px solid #fff;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
}

.dropdown input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .dropdown_button .arrow { border-color: white transparent transparent transparent }

.dropdown .dropdown_content {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
    padding: 7px;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
     -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
      transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.58) 0px 12px 25px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.58) 0px 12px 25px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.58) 0px 12px 25px;
     background: #fff;
     font-size: 12px;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
      -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
      -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
     border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
     min-width: 140px;
}

.dropdown .dropdown_content li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0px;
    line-height: 16px;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.dropdown .dropdown_content li:hover {
    background: #d32d41;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #9e2635;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px #f14a5e;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px #f14a5e;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px #f14a5e;
    border: 1px solid #9e2635;
    color: #fff;
      -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;

}

.dropdown .dropdown_content li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 7px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropdown .dropdown_content li:hover a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

.dropdown input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .dropdown_content { display: block }

.dropdown input[type="checkbox"] { display: none }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown" id="dropdown">
    <input type="checkbox" id="drop1" />
        <label for="drop1" class="dropdown_button">click here<span class="arrow"></span></label>
        <ul class="dropdown_content">
   <li><a href="*">User panel</a></li> 
   <li><a href="*">Log out</a></li>
   <li><a href="*">Edit profile</a></li>
   <li><a href="*">Edit options</a></li>
   <li><a href="*">Edit avatar</a></li>
   <li><a href="*">Edit signature</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Buddy list</a></li>
        </ul>       
    </div>
```

JSFIddle demo here

http://jsfiddle.net/andreas84x/x5wvnzt7/5/

Comment: With this code when I click outside the window doesn't hide.

Comment: Yea i' m not sure why it doesn't on here. it does on my site.. strange that

Comment: You mistakely have not linked jquery in the fiddle. thats the reason its not working in fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of **the cascading order**:

1. Browser default
2. External style sheet
3. Internal style sheet
4. Inline

When you click outside the dropdown it'll change the style attribute to display: none. Now when you trying to change the display to block/inline-block in css it doesn't take effect, because still inline display: none have priority.

**The solution**: use `fadeIn` on button click (remove this css fix) :)

Comment: Changing it to fadeIn doesn't fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Is this working. please check and reply.

check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x5wvnzt7/12/)

```
$(document).click(function (e){
var container = $(".dropdown_content");
if( container.is(':visible')) {
    if(e.target.id != "drop1"){
     $("#drop1").click();
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     .dropdown_content
        {
            display:none;
        }   



 $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".dropdown_button").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(".dropdown_content").show();
                });
            });

            $(document).click(function (e) {


                var container = $(".dropdown_content");
                if ($(e.target).closest(".dropdown_button").length > 0) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
                    //e.preventDefault();
                    container.fadeOut();


                }
                //e.preventDefault();

            });
```

Comment: This kinda worked lol. i can open the menu by clicking anywhere on screen plus it has a nice fade in and out effect.  anyway this could be tweaked so it only opens when clicking "click here"  but can be closed clicking anywhere?

Comment: @andreas yes i tried clicking anywhere to open and close ..not even on "click here"

Comment: No i mean i want the menu to open when only clicking "click here" but close by clicking anywhere, with your code it opens and closes anywhere

Answer (score -1):

Write your JavaScript code into Anonymous function

```
    $(function(){
      $(document).click(function (e)
      {

      var container = $(".dropdown_content");

       if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
      {
     container.fadeOut('slow');

       }

    });
  });
```

Comment: jsfiddle by default call javascript `onLoad`, see http://jsfiddle.net/x5wvnzt7/9/ (in your example problem still exists)

Comment: I've added an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/x5wvnzt7/9/) - try open the menu, then click outside it and try open it again (not working)